# Moving location of a database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I can't find the database that was created in my App.
I had a look at other similar questions here and I know it's probably because I don't have root privileges.
However, I can't find the actual app folder on the phone.
In Debug mode on the emulator it's in data, but I can't see it on the phone when I install the apk.
It gives no errors when I push the Buttons, so I assume the db is being created and usable.

The question is: is there any way to move the location of where a database is created so I can see it.
Also is there any better way of increasing a number on a database?

```
package com.example.a2618436.customersatsifaction;

/**
 * Created by 2618436 on 06/05/2016.

 */
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;

public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "SurveyDB.db";
    private static final String  TABLE_SURVEY = "Survey";

    public static final String KEY_ID= "id";
    public static final String KEY_HAPPY = "happy";
    public static final String KEY_SAD = "sad";

    public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name,
                       SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        String CREATE_SURVEY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
                TABLE_SURVEY + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_HAPPY
                + " INTEGER," + KEY_SAD + " INTEGER" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_SURVEY_TABLE);
    }

    //

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
                int newVersion){
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SURVEY);
        onCreate(db);

    }
    //needs revision
    public void addSurvey(MainActivity mainactivity) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_HAPPY, mainactivity.getHappy()); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_SAD, mainactivity.getSad()); // Contact Phone Number

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_SURVEY, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
}
```

The Database handler.

```
package com.example.a2618436.customersatsifaction;

/**
 * Created by 2618436 on 06/05/2016.

 */
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;

public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "SurveyDB.db";
    private static final String  TABLE_SURVEY = "Survey";

    public static final String KEY_ID= "id";
    public static final String KEY_HAPPY = "happy";
    public static final String KEY_SAD = "sad";

    public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name,
                       SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        String CREATE_SURVEY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
                TABLE_SURVEY + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_HAPPY
                + " INTEGER," + KEY_SAD + " INTEGER" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_SURVEY_TABLE);
    }

    //

        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
                    int newVersion){
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SURVEY);
            onCreate(db);

        }
        //needs revision
        public void addSurvey(MainActivity mainactivity) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(KEY_HAPPY, mainactivity.getHappy()); // Contact Name
            values.put(KEY_SAD, mainactivity.getSad()); // Contact Phone Number

            // Inserting Row
            db.insert(TABLE_SURVEY, null, values);
            db.close(); // Closing database connection
        }
    }
```

Comment: And WHY do you need to access the db on your device? You can inspect it in the DDMS (please consider developing on emulators, rather than on physical devices - which is a WORST PRACTICE).

Comment: **1** - You can create the database on the storage, if so you wish. Then you are exposed to spoofing. **2** - What do you mean by `Also is there any better way of increasing a number on a database?`?

Comment: I can't find the Database on the emulator so I don't think its actually been created.  Its not in the com.example folder where I presume it should be.

Comment: You are confused a lot. **1** - `I don't think its actually been created`. You would get an error when trying to access it, but you also affirm that `It gives no errors when I push the Buttons`. **2** -  `Its not in the com.example folder where I presume it should be.` You presume wrong. it's in `/data/data/my.app.name/databases/`, as usual.

Comment: Its not in /data/data/my.app.name/databases/ theres  cache, code_cache, files, instant run and dex but no data folder.  Also /data/data/my.app.name/ isn't showing up on the phone when i mistakenly tested it on it,

Comment: `my.app.name` must be replaced with your own package name, of course.

Comment: I now that lol but databases isn't there.  More importantly none of its in the same location on the phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are writing DB operation, you should have a rooted device or your can try for Genymotion(pre rooted) for this.You can see your db file `/data/data/com.yourpackage.com/databases/yourdb.db`.You can easily see db have data or not by installing [RootExplorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.rootexplorer) app.

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a go but databases isn't showing up so it doesn't look like the database is being created.  Is there anything I'm doing wrong in the code.

Comment: yes, you can try another way, copy yourdb.db file from assets to app when app first time lunch.

Comment: Thanks, wheres assets and how do you do that?